# using an Access Form for a 1 to 1 relationship

Tags: ms-access

I have a problem with saving a form in Access, i have 2 tables related by a 1:1 relationship :
(technically it's a 1 to many relationship but im using it this way )

Table 1 : id,.....

Table 2 : id,.....,table1_id

So i made a form for Table1 in access, and another one for Table2, in this form i use the first one as a subForm.

So what i need is to save the data after the user enters everything, i guess i'll have to save the data related to Table1 first and get the generated Id for the added row, and only after that submit the data for Table2,

how can i do that?

If there is still something unclear i can give more details.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: May I know, ID is a Auto Increment or just put yourself?

Comment: hi i found out that table_1 form should be the one containing table_2 subform (parent form must be for parent table), and then linking the related fields.